# How to use LINQ group by with where clause

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a list with data as mentioned below:

```
From        To      Gender    departure date
Delhi      Mumbai    M         16-Feb-18
Delhi      Mumbai    M         16-Feb-18
Delhi      Mumbai    F         16-Feb-18
Delhi      Mumbai    C         16-Feb-18
Mumbai     Mohili    F         16-Feb-18
Mumbai     Mohili    M         16-Feb-18
Mumbai     Mohili    C         16-Feb-18
```

I want to group this list based on `From` and `To` columns and calculate how many male, female and child are there in each group though LINQ. How can I do this.
I grouped it like  this but now how to calculate count of male and female.

```
var list = result.Journey.GroupBy(x => new { x.From, x.To });
```

Comment: If I also add class column to this list where each row belongs to a class like A, B, C,D then after applying GroupBy on From and To column how can I get count of male, female and child in each class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code,

```
        var list = travelars.GroupBy(x => new { x.From, x.To }).ToList().Select(e => new { 
            MaleCount = e.Count(g => g.Gender == "M"),
            FemaleCount = e.Count(g => g.Gender == "F"),
            ChildCount = e.Count(g => g.Gender == "C"),
        });
```

Comment: How does [linq-to-entities] handle splitting the query with that `ToList` call?  Does it (A) load the keys and issue followup 3*N queries for the counts or (B) load the groups with elements and calculate the rest by Enumeration.  Either way seems like misbehavior to me when a single query solution is available.

Comment: @AmyB  it will `load the groups with elements and calculate the rest by Enumeration`,

Comment: I had to make slight change in the query and it worked. below is the updated query.  var list = travelars.GroupBy(x => new { x.From, x.To }).ToList().Select(e => new { 
            MaleCount = e.Count(g => g.Gender == "M"),
            FemaleCount = e.Count(g => g.Gender == "F"),
            ChildCount = e.Count(g => g.Gender == "C"),
        });  Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @AshwiniKumar what about change?

Comment: How to accept it as answer as it has certainly helped me

Comment: @programtreasures: If I also add class column to this list where each row belongs to a class like A, B, C,D then after applying GroupBy on From and To column how can I get count of male, female and child in each class?

Comment: @AshwiniKumar if you are not including those columns in groupby the query will be as it is..

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to know is the return type of `GroupBy` is an `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`.  This grouping is enumerable and yields the elements when enumerated.  Therefore, groupings may be LINQ queried as any other enumerable.

```
var query = result.Journey
  .GroupBy(x => new { x.From, x.To })
  .Select(g => new
  {
    From = g.Key.From,
    To = g.Key.To,
    MCount = g.Count(x => x.Gender == "M"),
    FCount = g.Count(x => x.Gender == "F"),
    CCount = g.Count(x => x.Gender == "C")
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to not understand what `GroupBy` returns. It returns a bunch of groupings. Each `IGrouping<T, U>` is in and of itself an `IEnumerable<U>` of the things in that group.

What I suggest you do is to group the groupings again, by gender! This is so that even if a new gender has been added to the model, you don't have to add code to count the new gender.

```
// using the new C# 7 tuple syntax!
foreach(var group in Journeys.GroupBy(x => (x.To, x.From))) {
    Console.WriteLine($"People traveling from {group.Key.Item1} to {group.Key.Item2}:");
    foreach (var subgroup in group.GroupBy(x => x.Gender)) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{subgroup.Key}: {subgroup.Count()} people");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this,

```
  List<Journey> list = new List<Journey>();

            list.Add(new Journey() {From="Delhi",To="Mumbai",Gender=Gender.MALE });
            list.Add(new Journey() { From = "Delhi", To = "Mumbai", Gender = Gender.MALE });
            list.Add(new Journey() { From = "Delhi", To = "Mumbai", Gender = Gender.FEMALE });
            list.Add(new Journey() { From = "Delhi", To = "Mumbai", Gender = Gender.CHILD });
            list.Add(new Journey() { From = "Delhi", To = "Mumbai", Gender = Gender.MALE });
            list.Add(new Journey() { From = "Delhi", To = "Mumbai", Gender = Gender.MALE });
            list.Add(new Journey() { From = "Mumbai", To = "Mohili", Gender = Gender.FEMALE });
            list.Add(new Journey() { From = "Mumbai", To = "Mohili", Gender = Gender.CHILD });
            list.Add(new Journey() { From = "Mumbai", To = "Mohili", Gender = Gender.CHILD });

            var grp = list.GroupBy(s => new { s.From, s.To }).ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Select(i=>new JourneyCalc { From=i.From,To=i.To,Gender=i.Gender}).ToList());

            foreach (var item in grp)
            {
                var str = from val in item.Value group val by val.Gender into itmgrp select new JourneyCalc { Gender = itmgrp.Key, JourneyCount = itmgrp.Count() };
                foreach (JourneyCalc jc in str)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(value: $"{item.Value[0].From} - {item.Value[0].To} => {jc.Gender} - {jc.JourneyCount}");
                }
            } 



    public class JourneyCalc
    {
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string To { get; set; }
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }
        public int JourneyCount { get; set; }
    }
    public enum Gender
    {        
        MALE,
        FEMALE,
        CHILD
    }
    public class Journey
    {
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string To { get; set; }
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }

    }

Output:

Delhi - Mumbai => MALE - 4
Delhi - Mumbai => FEMALE - 1
Delhi - Mumbai => CHILD - 1
Mumbai - Mohili => FEMALE - 1
Mumbai - Mohili => CHILD - 2
```